# Apache Poi: Can custom properties on a worksheet level be accessed?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Can custom properties on worksheet level (in VBA accessed as Worksheet.CustomProperties) also be accessed via POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason - I've been struggling with the same issue and found a way to make it work, but it's far from optimal.  Here it is anyway and hopefully you or someone else can come up with a better method.

```
package temp.temp;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomProperty;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet;

public class Temp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\myspreadsheet.xlsx");
        try (BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); 
            
            for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                XSSFSheet sheet  = wb.getSheetAt(i);
                System.out.println("\nSheetName=" + sheet.getSheetName());
                
                CTWorksheet ctSheet = sheet.getCTWorksheet();
                CTCustomProperties props = ctSheet.getCustomProperties();
                
                if (props != null) {
                    List<CTCustomProperty> propList = props.getCustomPrList();
                    propList.stream().forEach((prop) -> {
                        POIXMLDocumentPart rel = sheet.getRelationById(prop.getId());
                        if (rel != null) {
                            try (InputStream inp  = rel.getPackagePart().getInputStream()) {
                                byte[] inBytes = inp.readAllBytes();
                                // By experimentation, byte array has two bytes per character with least 
                                //  significant in first byte which is UTF-16LE encoding.  Don't know why!
                                String value = new String(inBytes, "UTF-16LE");
                                System.out.println("   " + prop.getName() + "=" + value);
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                //Error
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                
            
            }
            wb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Note that CTWorksheet comes from poi-ooxml-schemas-xx.jar and CustomProperties from ooxml-schemas-yy.jar,  so both have to be on the classpath.  If you're using modules (as I am), this gives big problems!   Good Luck

Comment: This works for me as well.  Oddly I'm happy to hear I'm not the only one having this issue and I'm sure others are as well.  Thank you for the help!