# Sheet level custom properties using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is it possible to write custom properties at sheet level to a xlsx file using apache poi in java. Pls provide suggestions with code

Here's some code for reference

```
CTWorksheet ctSheet = sheet.getCTWorksheet(); CTCustomProperties props = ctSheet.getCustomProperties(); props.addNewCustomPr().set(Xmlobj)
```

[Apache Poi: Can custom properties on a worksheet level be accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64757565/apache-poi-can-custom-properties-on-a-worksheet-level-be-accessed)

Comment: Welcome to SO! In your own question you are providing the link to an answer... So which one is your problem? Please, clarify.

Comment: Thank u ! The link provide is to read custom properties at sheet level ! I needed help in writing custom properties at sheet level using poi ! That is the corresponding code to the code provided in the link.